# Issue loading file using Ajax on localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load in a CSV file to use in my code. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    //update CSV name to match your CSV
    var csv_name = "filename.csv";
    $.ajax({
    url: csv_name,
    dataType: 'text',
    }).done((data) => {parserFunction(data); chartsFunction(); calendarFunc();})
});
```

This works fine when I put the files on a proper web server (I'm using ecowebhosting if it matters), but when I try to open the files using Python's http.server command, I get this error:

jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:8000/Desktop/FolderName/filename.csv 404 (File not found)

Is there a fix to this? Can someone use my JavaScript code without having to pay for a web server/website (In other words, can it be run locally)? Sorry if this sounds dumb; I'm an extremely beginner web developer.